# What is the fastest and most concise way to select the first character of a string using PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell, text-extraction

**Aim:** To extract the first character from a string, i.e., `8` should be extracted from `8.0.26`

**Attempt:** `"8.0.26".substring(0,1)` returns `8`

**Question:** Is this the fastest and most concise way of selecting the first character from a string using PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any proof, but this snippet seems to demonstrate that indexing (as in briantist's answer) is faster.

```
"starting"

$foo = "hello"
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 1000000; $i++) {
    $bar = $foo[0]
    #$bar = $foo.substring(0,1)
}

"stopping"
```

Try it yourself and see.

Update: Ran Measure-Command and confirmed that on my computer that indexing into the string is faster than substring. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: If you wanted to really check that, you could wrap it in `Measure-Command` :)

Comment: Also remember that indexing returns a `[char]`, if a `[string]` is needed (unclear) then it should be measured with the cast.

Comment: @briantist Good points both. It gets a bit slower with [string] on it but still appears faster than substring. I'll leave Measure-Command as an exercise to the asker :)

Comment: @briantist Who am I kidding - my curiosity got the better of me. It is faster (takes around 3 seconds compared to 4) to use the index (with cast) versus substring. Without the cast, it's closer to 2 seconds.

Comment: Haha, great work; you already have my vote otherwise I'd vote again.

Answer (score 3):

I mean I guess it depends on what you mean by fastest. Most performant? Fastest to type? Do you want is as a `[char]` or as a `[string]`?

```
"8.0.26"[0]
[string]"8.0.26"[0]
```